# Joining 3 tables and adding a total column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in a `MySQL` database

Table 1(`vendors`) contains all of my `vendors`

Table 2(`puchaseorders`) contains all of my `purchaseorders` and with a common column being 'vendor'

Table 3 contains all of the individual items from those orders with a common column being `purchase_order`

In the vendors table I have a historical balance that I want to add the running total to.

This is what I have right now. It works perfect but it only returns the vendors that are in the `purchaseorders` table.

I want to return all of the vendors in the vendors table. If there isn't a "running_total" don't do anything to the balance.

```
SELECT *, vendors.balance + vend.running_total AS total FROM vendors 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT vendor, SUM(orderhistory.qty_received *                         
orderhistory.estimated_price) AS running_total FROM orderhistory 
INNER JOIN purchaseorders ON 
orderhistory.purchase_order=purchaseorders.purchase_order
GROUP BY purchaseorders.vendor) AS vend ON vend.vendor=vendors.vendor;
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Comment: Use left join instead of inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (`LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL`)

```
SELECT *, vendors.balance + IFNULL(vend.running_total,0) AS total
FROM vendors 
LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT vendor, SUM(orderhistory.qty_received * orderhistory.estimated_price) AS running_total
    FROM orderhistory 
    INNER JOIN purchaseorders ON orderhistory.purchase_order=purchaseorders.purchase_order
    GROUP BY purchaseorders.vendor
  ) AS vend
ON vend.vendor=vendors.vendor;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the join outside to left join and use a coalesce around `vend.running_total` field so that it is treated as 0 if it is not present in the inner table and as a non-zero value if present. Try:

```
SELECT *, vendors.balance + COALESCE(vend.running_total,0) AS total 
FROM vendors 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT vendor, SUM(orderhistory.qty_received * orderhistory.estimated_price) AS running_total 
FROM orderhistory INNER JOIN purchaseorders 
ON orderhistory.purchase_order = purchaseorders.purchase_order
GROUP BY purchaseorders.vendor) AS vend 
ON vend.vendor=vendors.vendor;
```